# Xamarin Entry Field (iOS) - Right Aligned Text

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to create `<Entry>` field with `HorizontalTextAlignment="End"`. When typing more than one word (ex: Burger King), hitting the spacebar between the words does nothing. Once you hit the "K" in King, it will add the space and register the K. This behavior only happens on iOS from what I can tell.

I have tried `OnTextChanged` Invalidating the size hoping this would redraw the input, but this was not working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example of the code I am working with.

```
<StackLayout 
    VerticalOptions="Center">
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Merchant" 
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Entry 
        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
        Placeholder="Name" 
        PlaceholderColor="Black"></Entry>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: The cursor doesn't move when you type a space but the space is there, and the space appears when you type the next character.

Comment: Correct, this looks strange from a user perspective. I would continue to hit the spacebar. Wondering if this is an intended behavior, or if anyone has thought of a fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem on Xcode. The Entry control in Forms corresponds to the native UITextField of iOS. On Xcode, I use UITextField to align the text to the right and click the space, but it cannot be displayed, so this is not a Forms problem, it is native to iOS.